# ZF: Problema ao gerar PDF (com mPDF) a partir de texto (html) criado com WYSIWYNG (plugin elrte)

Tags: zend, pdf

Galera,

Estou com problema na geração de PDF em texto que contenha *tag* `<table>`. Neste caso estou criando um módulo para geração de contratos.

O texto vem do banco e é criado a partir de um `WYSIWYNG` (*plugin elrte*).
Formatações na tabela não são renderizadas no PDF, causando empilhamento das palavras contidas na tabela.

Para geração do PDF estou utilizando *mPDF*.

Alguém já passou por isso? Alguma solução?

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($lsConteudo); //$lsConteudo vem do BD.

$mpdf->Output('contrato.pdf' , 'D');
```

Comment: eu estou com um problema parecido atualmente, mas diminui os problemas consideravelmente na geração dos PDFS removendo o CSS padrão que ele define no **config.php**

Comment: Vc removeu no próprio arquivo Leandro, ou existe algum método para desabilitar o carregamento?

Comment: removi manualmente no arquivo config.php do mPDF, tem um array lá com uns estilos padrão que ele inclusive aplica na hora que você manda gerar o PDF, o que implica nos problemas que você teve. mas nem tudo ele gera corretamente.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar remover e ver se tenho um resultado melhor.

Comment: sim, olha o exemplo no fim do código http://pastebin.com/DsaXUPyf

Comment: Não funcionou neste caso Leandro, mesmo retirando a formatação default.

Comment: dê uma olhada na documentação http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34, não sei se vai te ajudar, no caso aqui, o pessoal resolveu fazer com outro gerador de pdf, chamado **snappy** https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy

Comment: É a documentação dele é mto vaga... não dá mtos exemplos de utilização de tabelas.

Comment: com tabelas ele se mostrou horrível.

Comment: Pessoal, ainda não consegui achar uma solução para esta questão preciso de mais sugestões... alguém?

Comment: conseguiu? se nao a gente procura uma solução juntos! =)

Comment: Uso o mPDF com o Smarty e chamo o css via link rel (<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pdf.css">) no meu template, e funciona perfeitamente. já tentou colocar a referência ao css direto?

Answer (score 2):

Transformar HTML em PDF nem sempre é tão simples, pois é necessário renderizar o conteúdo e então depois convertê-lo. As soluções que tentam converter o HTML para PDF baseado no style ou pressuposições simplistas tendem a ter muitas limitações, como com as tags table, img, etc.

A melhor alternativa provavelmente seja usar um renderizador HTML webkit que converta para PDF ou PNG, como preferir. O http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ é um dos melhores, temos usado há anos em um ambiente bem agressivo de conversão de tudo o que é tipo de documento, inclusive com imagens, CSS, tables, cabeçalhos e rodapés, margens customizadas, tudo:

1) Instale o wkhtmltopdf no servidor.
2) Crie um script (PHP, Perl, como tu quiser) que receba o HTML, invoque o comando wkhtmltopdf e dê a saída application/pdf de volta para o cliente.
3) Na página web, via javascript dê um POST do conteúdo HTML para o script criado no server-side.

Se já estiver no server-side e usar PHP, já existe inclusive um projeto que faz esse port: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Eu fiz um IPC direto com o executável wkhtmltopdf para ter controle total não deu mais de 10 linhas (no meu caso em PERL). Em PHP deve ser bem simples também.

Answer (score 0):

A biblioteca HTML2PDF consegue apresentar alguns resultados bem interessantes mesmo com HTMLs envolvendo tabelas. Acho que você poderia tentar usá-la e ver se atende suas necessidades.

Um dos problemas de editores WYSIWYNG é que eles costumam "sujar" o HTML, dificultando o trabalho deste tipo de conversor.

Link da biblioteca
http://html2pdf.fr/en/default